Запуск bat-файла на удаленном компьютере через cmd

На удаленном ПК хранится bat-файл. Нужно его запустить.
Пытался просто прописать путь по сети с указанием файла, но открывается у меня на компьютере.
\\namePC\c$\Temp\install_msi_locally.bat


интерфейс \\server\share\path даёт доступ к удалённым файлам и никак не поможет с созданием процессов на удалённом компе

psexec пробовали?

Можно использовать утилиту psexec  от SysInternals (теперь уже от Microsoft). Подробней тут

через cmd можно запустить что либо на удаленном сервере при помощи telnet
telnet опции хост порт

подробнее тут
